# How do I redirect my site using a .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

How do I redirect my site using a `.htaccess`?

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php
```

to:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?page=search
```

It's not working in `.htaccess`:

`redirect 301 /index.php http://domain.com/index.php?page=search`

Answer (score 0):

With Redirect directive you can not redirect **/index.php** to **/index.php?page=search** as it will redirect to the same location causing a Redirect loop error, You need to use mod-rewrite :

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php?page=search [NC,L,R]
```

Remove the R flag if you an invisible redirection.

Comment: @Mert This is a tested code. and it works fine on my apache server. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: I added the code in .htaccess. I'm sure. I added correctly. But not redirect.

Comment: @Mert I think mod-rewrite isnt enabled on your server. do you any other working RewriteRules in htaccess?

Comment: mod-rewrite is enabled on server. yes, other working RewriteRules in htaccess.

Comment: @Mert then what do you mean by **not working** ? what happens when you go to /index.php ?

Comment: check it pls: http://www.yokyok.us/index.php Htaccess Image: http://oi64.tinypic.com/205tedc.jpg

Comment: @Mert I saw the img, you have a rule **RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]** conflicting with my code. Reorder your rules, put my code above the rule.